# Parsing multiple XML files using multithreading with SAXParser

Tags: java, xml, multithreading, parsing, sax

I have a timer which checks for new XML files on the file system and parses them. XML files can get large(5GB), so i am using sax parser. To increase the productivity, i wrote a multithreading programm with executer service.

XML files can belong to different sources. For each source is being a thread created and in this thread XML files parsed which belong to the source. In every thread a new SaxParserFactory and for every XML file a new SaxParser created.

The problem is that different parser kill each others process. When i check the parse results, i notice that some of the XML's haven't been parsed completely. The parser quits halfway and doesn't throw any exception. I dont have the problem when the XML files is being parsed in single thread.

Now i am not sure, if the SaxParserFactory and SaxParser really create new instances.

Do you guys have any idea what might cause this?

```
SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
AccountSaxHandler saxHandler = new AccountSaxHandler();
parser.parse(new File(localFilePath), saxHandler);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23214773/concurrent-sax-processing-of-large-simple-xml-files

Comment: Not really, i dont want to split XML file in multiple threads.